# How to merge to sound files in WP8?

Tags: windows-phone-8, wav, xaudio2, wasapi

It it possible to merge sound captured from microphone with an mp3 file selected and save as a new mp3 file in windows phone 8?

Does naudio have wp8 support??

Answer (score 1):

Possible, yes. But you would have to decode the mp3 file into raw PCM data that matches the waveformat of the captured audio data, merge the pcm data (either an additive or mean merge or you'd simply add the captured audio data to the end of the pcm data from the mp3) and encode your new pcm data to MP3. There are plenty of libraries out there that support encoding/decoding of mp3 data and you might even find one that would let you decode/re-encode only the sub-sample of the mp3 file that you're interested in merging with captured audio data.

NAudio has, AFAIK, no WP8 support. I believe that they're currently working on Windows Store App support.

You would need to use WASAPI - which is a native-only API - or the Microsoft.XNA.Audio.Microphone-class to capture data.